# how to open facebook session in android

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am developing a simple app which login facebook .
I am trying to display the facebook profile name in the textview..

I am creating the app on facebook and also put appId into menifest .

In my app can not cause any error but it can't display the Facebook profile name into textview .

I found that the facebook session is not open thats why it can't connect to my bacebook account...

Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                System.out.println("Session is open....");

                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                  // callback after Graph API response with user object
                  @Override
                  public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                      TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                      if (user != null) {
                          welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                          System.out.println("Hello " + user.getName());
                        }
                      else {
                        welcome.setText("User not present");
                    }
                  }
                });
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Session is not open....");
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}}
```

Can anybody tell mi how to connect to facebook session...

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be in key Hash.

You shud definitely see this tutorial:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Look at the `Troubleshooting` section, that might help you

Comment: I am refereeing this tutorial for developing this app.It can't give any error but can not connect to profile